# Oracle ODBC Connection - Unable to Run Queries

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

I'm developing a C# application that will connect to a local data source and extract data from it. The problem I'm having is if I try running a query such as "SELECT SYSDATA FROM DUAL" I get the following message:

**Error: OverflowException error caught.

Message: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.**

I get the same message if I try any other query.

The program is built as a 64-bit application.
The database is stored locally on the machine.
The driver used by the data source is Oracle in OraClient 11g_home2.
The driver version is 11.02.00.01.

Here is my connection code:

```
try {
        string connectionString =
            "DSN="+_dsn+
            ";DBQ="+_dbq+
            ";DBA=R"+
            ";Uid="+_uid+
            ";Pwd="+_pwd;

        using (_odbc_conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString)) {

            Console.WriteLine("Establishing connection...");
            _odbc_conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("\nConnection successful!\n");

            Console.WriteLine("== Connection Status ==");
            Console.WriteLine("Connection String: " + _odbc_conn.ConnectionString);
            Console.WriteLine("Connection State: " + _odbc_conn.State);
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Timeout: " + _odbc_conn.ConnectionTimeout);
            Console.WriteLine("Database: " + _odbc_conn.Database.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Data Source: " + _odbc_conn.DataSource);
            Console.WriteLine("Driver: " + _odbc_conn.Driver);
            Console.WriteLine("Server Version: " + _odbc_conn.ServerVersion);
            Console.WriteLine("Schema: " + _odbc_conn.GetSchema() + "\n");

            if (_odbc_conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
                Console.WriteLine("== Query Results ==");                   
                RunQuery();
            }
        }

    } catch(OdbcException e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to establish connection!");
        for (int i=0; i<e.Errors.Count; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                "Message: " + e.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                "NativeError: " + e.Errors[i].NativeError.ToString() + "\n" +
                "Source: " + e.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                "SQL: " + e.Errors[i].SQLState + "\n");
        }
    }
```

If somebody can please help with this I would hugely appreciate it.
Thank you!

EDIT: I forgot my query code:

```
private void RunQuery() {
    try {
        _odbc_cmd = new OdbcCommand();
        _odbc_cmd.Connection = _odbc_conn;
        _odbc_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL";
        _odbc_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } catch (OdbcException e) {
    ...

    _odbc_conn.Close();
}
```

EDIT #2: Syntax change without success.

```
_odbc_cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL", _odbc_conn);
using (OdbcDataReader reader = _odbc_cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

This results in the same arithmetic error as before.

Comment: can this be exception in your for (int i=0; i<e.Errors.Count; i++) { } cycle? if you remove the catch what exception system raises?

Comment: Why are you using `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute a query?

Comment: @are I get the same: OverflowException error caught; Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: see the topic: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2484113 they said it can be ODBC driver issue.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis I just tried changing the syntax. I'll add it as a 2nd edit to my original post.

Comment: @are That is certainly possible, I'll look into that.

Comment: I just edited my post to include the driver version, if that helps at all.